# Why CSS float makes paragraph behave that way

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to fully understand why CSS `float` property behaves as the snippet shows:

```css
p {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    background-color: rgba(111, 41, 97, .3);
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <p>Pea horseradish azuki bean lettuce avocado asparagus okra. Kohlrabi radish okra azuki bean corn fava bean mustard tigernut jícama green bean celtuce. </p>
        <p>Grape silver beet collard greens avocado quandong fennel gumbo black-eyed pea watercress potato tigernut corn groundnut. Chickweed okra pea winter purslane coriander yarrow sweet pepper radish garlic brussels sprout groundnut summer purslane earthnut
            pea tomato spring onion azuki bean gourd. Gumbo kakadu plum komatsuna black-eyed pea green bean zucchini gourd winter purslane silver beet rock melon radish asparagus spinach.</p>
    </div>
```

Let me explain: As the `div` has been floated to left, it is not in the normal flow anymore. Because that, the `p` element overlaps it. However, the text that belongs to `p` does not behave the same way and wraps the `div`. Why the text of `p` element behaves that way? I would have expect that the text also overlaps the `div`.

Why the `width` and `height` and `margin` of the `div` are affecting the text of `p` but not the `p`itself?

Comment: my tip is to leave the `float` behind in the '90s and use `flex-box` or `grid` for layout styling

Comment: @MatanSanbira - Can you demonstrate how to get the text to wrap around the div elerment as shown in the snippet by using flex-box and/or grid, but not using float.

Comment: I know other duplicate explaining float well, need some time to find them

Comment: added more duplicate that should help you better understand float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much the definition of what a float does.

Formally, the p element establishes an Inline Formatting Context. Its content box contains a stack of line boxes. Each line box is shortened so that it doesn't overlap with the margin box of the floated element. The text is placed in inline boxes inside the line boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Float property definition is like below:
**The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow.**

Refer this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score -1):

you can read more here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  background-color: rgba(111, 41, 97, .3);
}

.img-text-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.img-text-container p {
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-text-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <p>
      Pea horseradish azuki bean lettuce avocado asparagus okra. Kohlrabi radish okra azuki bean corn fava bean mustard tigernut jícama green bean celtuce.
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>Grape silver beet collard greens avocado quandong fennel gumbo black-eyed pea watercress potato tigernut corn groundnut. Chickweed okra pea winter purslane coriander yarrow sweet pepper radish garlic brussels sprout groundnut summer purslane earthnut
    pea tomato spring onion azuki bean gourd. Gumbo kakadu plum komatsuna black-eyed pea green bean zucchini gourd winter purslane silver beet rock melon radish asparagus spinach.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how this is related to the question?

Comment: he asked me to show him how to do it with flex....

Comment: you are showing that it cannot be done with flex. Your code doesn't produce the same behavior as float (and will never do)